# Как обработать строку с шаблоном?

Tags: javascript, строки

Подскажите стратегию работы с шаблоном на таком примере:
Пользователь вводит строку вида "Просто текст {{маркер_1}}, ещё текст {{маркер_2}}, бла-бла-бла.", а результатом обработки будет строка, в которой маркеры будут заменены на нечто, чему они соответствуют.
Я пока представляю себе только сложный перебор строки в поисках всех фигурных скобок, обнаружения их содержимого, сравнения с некоторым готовым набором переменных. Но чувствую, что есть и хороший способ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let str = "Просто текст {{маркер_1}}, ещё текст {{маркер_2}}, бла-бла-бла.";

console.log(
  str.replace('{{маркер_1}}', 'Мой текст 1')
    .replace('{{маркер_2}}', '2-ой мой текст')
  )
```